# C# combobox for report viewer to code it

Tags: c#

[image: [enter image description here]]

```
faCRMstrBindingSource.DataSource = db.faCRMstr(dtpFrom.Value,dtpTo.Value).Tolist();


Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[] rParams = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]


     new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("StartDate",dtpFrom.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()),

     new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("EndDate",dtpTo.Value.Date.ToShortDateString())

};
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rParams);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}

// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.faCRMstr' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

this.faCRMstrTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.faCRMstr, dtpFrom.Text, dtpTo.Text);
//this.faCRMstrTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.vsmmc_patientmonitoring, dtpFrom.Text, dtpTo.Text);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is your problem ? What is the behavior of this code ? How is it different from what you would expect ?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply

Comment: i want to have a combobox in my report to filter a data in my database, and i can choose the list of data which i can generate the report with parameter with date filter and data filter